# Pig UDF - Return dynamic schema as a set of fields (not tuple)

Tags: apache-pig, jython, user-defined-functions

After a GROUP BY + FLATTEN I have a data with namespace:

```
DESCRIBE users;
users: {user_id: int, group_id: int, registration_timestamp: int}

users_with_namespace = FOREACH (GROUP users BY group_id) {
    first_to_latest = ORDER users BY registration_timestamp ASC;
    first_user = LIMIT first_to_latest 1;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(first_user);
};

DESCRIBE users_with_namespace;
users_with_namespace: {first_user::user_id: int, first_user::group_id: int, first_user::registration_timestamp: int}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
users = myudf.strip_namespace(users_with_namespace);
```

or (since, that doesn't seem to be possible):

```
users = FOREACH (GROUP users_with_namespaceALL) 
GENERATE myudf.strip_namespace(users_with_namespace);
```

With result being:

```
> DESCRIBE users;
users: {user_id: int, registration_timestamp: int}
```

I've written a Jython Pig UDF, which was supposed to strip field names of any namespace, but I can't seem to be able to return a set of fields from my UDF. Only a Bag/Tuple/Single field is possible, which leaves me with a result like this:

```
DESCRIBE users;
users: {t: (user_id: int, registration_timestamp: int)}
```

Is there any way to omit the 't' and return a list/set of fields? My UDF looks like this:

```
@outputSchemaFunction("tupleSchema")
def strip_namespace(input):
    return input


@schemaFunction("tupleSchema")
def tupleSchema(input):
    fields = []
    dt = []
    for i in input.getField(0).schema.getFields():
        for field in i.schema.getFields():
            fields.append(field.alias.split("::")[-1])
            dt.append(field.type)
    return SchemaUtil.newTupleSchema(fields, dt)
```

So far I've used

```
FOREACH .. GENERATE namespace::field as field, ...
```

to strip namespaces but this method is really tedious for data sets with many fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, at least not right now. The problem is exactly what you said: right now you can only return a Tuple, a Bag or a single field. I created a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4583) to allow to return multiple fields for this scenario 2 months ago, but no reply yet...

I really hope they implement this in the future, because when you have to perform many joins you end up with more `FOREACH` statements to rename fields than actual code.